# Certificate chain lost apache 2.4

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-2.4

So I think I'm not getting something here.

I'm getting

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain

when I access my application via apache httpd, but not when I'm accessing it directly. So is there any reason why my certificate can got lost on the way in my request to apache?

This is not a self signed certificate, but the real mccoy.

Comment: Are you accessing it via HTTPS and redirecting to 8080? When you say it's working is it on 8443? I assume this is tomcat or jetty on the back end? Looks like you only have the server cert but not intermediate/CA certs, if httpd is signing your HTTPS traffic try adding the CA & any intermediate CA certs to the pem file Apache is using (or the JKS file if httpd is just passing the traffic through to Tomcat).